# How to install TuringMachine's OMXPlayer?

Tags: software-installation, ffmpeg

Could someone please provide instructions on how to install [TuringMachine's OMXPlayer](https://github.com/turingmachine/omxplayer-sync)? I think he expected zero people to download it. That's the only explanation of have for the terrible documentation.

Specifically, the build of his fork (hosted here) does not work for me, giving the below error, and if I try to build it from source, `ffmpeg` will not install (again, I might be issuing the wrong commands)

```
./omxplayer.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libavutil.so.52: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: there's a working omxplayer on RaspberryPi, why do you need some non-working half-cooked fork, that was never intended to be used on RaspberryPi ?

Comment: @lenik lol, I want to be able to synchronize multiple movies across multiple raspis. It was my understanding that omxplayer cant do this, and other players which can do this (ie. vlc and mplayer) can **not** use the hardware acceleration of the raspi

Comment: how precise do you need to synchronize? 1sec? 1msec?

Comment: Precise enough such that the audio delay is not noticeable. The TVs will be in different rooms so they need not be visually identical. If this doesn't work, then I will have to centralize all the audio somehow

Comment: @AwesomeUser yes I did, I will add an answer now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to both download the binary, and install from source, but installing from source is extremely **extremely** difficult, contrary to what people say, as it requires a cross compiler. Also, before proceeding, bear in mind that this synchronizing script is written in python, so it is not very good.

**Downloading Binary:**
This is the easiest way to do it, but it is not simply drag and drop. First, download version[c0dd950](http://omxplayer.sconde.net/builds/omxplayer_0.3.2~git20131105~c0dd950_armhf.deb) of omxplayer. Next move it to wherever you have omxplayer installed (**warning** this will overwrite your existing omxplayer...also just renaming it to something else, like `omxplayer-sync` won't work). Next, launch the program, and when it fails, look for the the libraries it is missing, (ie. `/usr/local/libav`) then locate that library on your computer and link where it actually is to where the downloaded build of omxplayer is looking for it.

Once that is installed, you can download [omxplayer-sync](https://github.com/turingmachine/omxplayer-sync) and use it to synchronize the videos.

Comment: Good answer! Also, thank you for doing this, it is greatly appreciated. Try popping into chat from time to time, we always love company and it shows that we are a growing, involved community.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness no problem. By "chat" do you mean the comment section?

Comment: @AwesomeUser No, by chat I mean [The Bakery](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3748/the-bakery).